# Does anybody know or know where to find the requirements for Russian ice axe tests?

Tags: ice-axes, russia

As I bought an ice axe from Russia some 10-15 years ago and cannot remember their ratings, I just wondered if somebody knew (or knew where to find) descriptions of the Russian ice axe test requirements?

[For example](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/3616/what-s-the-difference-between-a-b-and-a-t-ice-axe), UIAA B/"Basic" axes can take 250kg sideways shaft/head interface load; UIAA T/"Technical" axes can take 400kg etc.

Comment: By UK B/T, do you mean UIAA B/T or is there really a rating specific to/originating in the UK?

Comment: No, you are right, thank you, I mean the UIAA ones as example.

Comment: @nsandersen Is there any kind of number on it anywhere? Many Russian and Soviet products are subject to GOST quality standards, and will have a number:  ГОСТ NNNN-YYYY, where N equals serial or related number and Y equals year. you can google GOST for more specifics

Comment: I will have a look later, thanks - unfortunately the axe and I are not in the same country right now!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there are no specific ice axe test requirements in Russia.
I didn't find any GOST standard for an ice axe as well.
So, if your ice axe isn't UIAA certified **you can just guess about whether it's reliable or not**.

Comment: OK, thank you. The seller seemed to indicate something existed. In either case not a problem, I got what I wanted and it is undoubtedly good enough for my winter mountain walking, which does not involve climbing.

Comment: @nsandersen I can try to look for more info if you'll send a photo of the ice axe.